# Way to make a counter in lightning controller

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I am trying to increase a value on every button click in a lightning component.  Is there a way to get a variable outside of individual function so I dont have to set the variable

```
({
function: (cmp, helper, event){
/////sample code 
},
 function2: (cmp, helper, event){
    var counter = 0;
    counter++;
    }
})
```

function2 is being called by a click event on a lightning button, but since the "counter" variable is being set every time it will never increase on-click

Comment: you can create aura:attribute and set that variable

Comment: but every time I cmp.get() on a click event, that variable will be reset as well

Comment: add your code with aura:attribute and then we will rectify that

Comment: @Himanshu, I was not "cmp.set"-ing the value, just trying to console.log it.  That was the problem so the solution was: set the attribute, cmp.get() in the controller, counter varible++, cmp.set(), then I could see it in the console.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code should look like this.

component.cmp

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="counter" default="0" type="integer"/>

    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" onclick="{!c.handleClick }" />

    Counter value is : {!v.counter}
</aura:component>
```

js

```
({
    handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {

        component.set('v.counter',component.get('v.counter')+1);

    }
})
```

Now you can refer counter variable anywhere in your controller